# Setup OpenId and AspCore behind load balancer

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3, asp.net-core, load-balancing, openid

I currently have an asp.net Core application that uses OpenId Connect for authentication using Google accounts. When this application gets deployed and sits behind the load balancer, it fails on the redirect to the sign-in page because it sets the uri as http instead of https, it also sets the redirect uri for the openid server as without https, is there a way to setup the options so it knows it should use https?

Comment: Take the x-forwarded headers and apply them to the request before auth. There is a UseForwardedHeaders middleware for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment by @Tratcher this got solved by building middleware that checks for the X-Forwarded headers as follows:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-Proto") || 
      context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-For"))
  {
      context.Request.Scheme = "https";
  }
  await next.Invoke();
});
```