Invalid authorization code when multiple instances of Identity Server 4
We are running into wierd issues since we scale out our azure app service plan. All this time we were on single instance hence no issue faced there. With mutiple instance running we persistenly get invalid access token error.
Few article pointed out that we need to share signing certificate and data protection key among all instances of IDS. For this we did below two changes.

Generated a signing key certificate using the below command and imported it to the certificate section of app service

Step 1) req -x509 -config "D:\OpenSSL\openssl.cnf" -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout RatingsIDSCert.key -out RatingsIDSCert.crt -subj "/CN=enterprise.ratings.com" -days 365
Step 2) pkcs12 -export -out RatingsIdsCert.pfx -inkey RatingsIDSCert.key -in RatingsIDSCert.crt -certfile RatingsIDSCert.crt
Removed developer signin certificate and load it from the certificate store of app service.
Removed// .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
Added// .AddSigningCredential(GetIdentityServerSigningCertificate())

Persisted data protection key in azure container

services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("KeyFileSasUrl")) .SetApplicationName("QARatingsIDS");
Even after performing the above two steps, we still run into the same issue. The token still fails and on subsequent retry it pass.
Any help is appreciated :)
`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddOptions();
        //services.Configure<ConfigSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
        // services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add(AccountOptions.EmailProvider,
            new TokenProviderDescriptor(
           typeof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>)));
            options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = AccountOptions.EmailProvider;
            options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = AccountOptions.EmailProvider;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            //lock for 1 year, basically we need to lock him indefinitely until he resets his password
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration.GetSection("MaxFailedLoginAttemptsAllowed").Value);


        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        //lifespan for email confirmation token:
        services.AddTransient<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddSingleton<IClientStore, ClientStore>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(HtmlEncode));
        });
        services.AddScoped<RateLimit>();
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("KeySaSUrl"))
            .SetApplicationName("QARatingsIDS");

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        })
            .AddSigningCredential(GetIdentityServerSigningCertificate())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddClientStore<ClientStore>()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
        
        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            options.HttpsPort = 443;
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddHttpClient<ReCaptcha>(x =>
        {
            x.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
        });
    }`

//Client Startup COnfiguration
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthenticationPatched(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "ratingspro.web",
            Authority = IdsvrConstants.BaseAddress,
            RedirectUri = baseClientAddress + "signin-oidc/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = baseClientAddress + "signout-callback-oidc/",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "openid api1 ratingspro.webapi offline_access",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationType,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    var client = HttpClientFactory.Create();
                    LogHelper.LogMessage(string.Format("RatingsproApp: Startup => : Code: {0}, RedirectUri: {1}", n.Code, n.RedirectUri));
                    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
                    {
                        Address = IdsvrConstants.TokenEndpoint,
                        ClientId = "ratingspro.web",
                        ClientSecret = "secret",
                        Code = n.Code,
                        RedirectUri = n.RedirectUri,
                    });
                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        LogHelper.LogMessage("RatingsproApp: Startup => tokenResponseError: " + tokenResponse.Error);
                        throw new AuthenticationException(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }
                    var userInfoResponse = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
                    {
                        Address = IdsvrConstants.UserInfoEndpoint,
                        Token = tokenResponse.AccessToken
                    });
                    if (userInfoResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new AuthenticationException(userInfoResponse.Error);
                    }
                    var claims = userInfoResponse.Claims;

                    if (claims.Any(c => c.Type == "ApplicationAccessDenied"))
                    {
                        throw new AuthenticationException(claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "ApplicationAccessDenied").Value);
                    }
                    // create new identity
                    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                    id.AddClaims(claims);
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("AccessToken", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    client.Dispose();
                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        n.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                    else if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = x =>
                {
                    string errorMessage = "";
                    if (x.Exception != null)
                    {
                        errorMessage = "Error: " + x.Exception.Message + " Stack StackTrace: " + x.Exception.StackTrace;
                        if (x.Exception.InnerException != null)
                        {
                            errorMessage += "Inner Error: " + x.Exception.InnerException.Message + " Stack StackTrace: " + x.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace;
                        }
                    }
                    LogHelper.LogMessage("RatingsproApp: Startup => AuthenticationFailed: " + errorMessage);
                    x.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "/";
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }
        });


I think the same instance issueing the OIDC authentication reuest, must be the same that then finalizes the request (accepting the authorization code).

Hi @ToreNestenius, Thank you for taking the time to help us out :). I have updated the description with the client startup configuration. Any issues flaged are appreciated.
Also, IDS does not always identify access tokens as invalid. On a subsequent retry, it does identify it as a valid access token. We feel like the token issued by one server fails to get validated at second server.

you should try to determine why access tokens are rejected in the API, see my blog post here https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Thanks, @ToreNestenius; I will do that. I enabled log level to trace, and while running the project locally, I got the below information.
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
You are using the in-memory version of the Persisted Grant Store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh tokens, and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.

exactly where and when do you get the error?

what is UseOpenIdConnectAuthenticationPatched?

@ToreNestenius, when I ran the project locally with the log level as a trace, I got this information. How do I go about creating a persistent grant store?
Regarding the UseOpenIdConnectAuthenticationPatched, I really don't have any clue. It is in our legacy code.

If you get problems with "Invalid authorization code, then the problem is not related to SigningCredential, instead it is related to AddDataProtection  https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/  , se also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580014/setup-openid-and-aspcore-behind-load-balancer

@ToreNestenius , I tried persisting the data protection key in Azure storage. The system updated the key file with the key ID. Will there still be a possibility that the key is not the same across instances? IDS doesn't really give a full error message but a generic invalid access token on the IDs side and an invalid grant on the client side.
Will it still be fine if we enable the in-memory persistance grant in a multi-instance environment? Azure scale-out creates multiple instances of the VM, hence confirming.

I would first look in the logs, to identify exactly what fails and the error that you get. I would also in the log verify that both instances do get the same data protection api key. But usually, the load-balancer should pin the same client instance (using a cookie).

set logging to verbose on the dataproteciton namespace as well

Hi @ToreNestenius, enabled trace level logging on Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection and IdentityServer4. Found below info
2024-04-22 18:25:54.7157||TRACE|IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint|Code issued for ratingspro.web (RatingsPro Web) / 91864fd3-81b0-4e64-90b9-c61810e5997f: 07aea24c877ddcf90563112890b56029992964f57aab3de8ce9f632a471f8add |url: https://login-qa.spherexratings.com/connect/authorize|action:

2024-04-22 18:25:55.6543||DEBUG|IdentityServer4.Stores.DefaultAuthorizationCodeStore|authorization_code grant with value: 07aea24c877ddcf90563112890b56029992964f57aab3de8ce9f632a471f8add not found in store. |url: https://login-qa.spherexratings.com/connect/token|action:

can you find the token it looks for inside the database? the issued auth codes are stored there.

Hi @ToreNestenius, Currently inmemory store is used. Do I need to change the Persistent store?

If you run multiple instances of IdentityServer, then you should use a shared storage.

Thanks @ToreNestenius, for confirming.  Will make those changes and observe the application behaviour. Will seek your help if I face anything. Thank you for your guidance here :). Appreciate your timely responses.

let me know if it works, if so, then I can write a more formal answer to your question ehre

Sure @ToreNestenius, will let you know about the outcome.
